A sequence of continuum hypotheses
The continuum hypothesis asserts that $\aleph_{1}=\beth_{1}$. Both it and its negation can be consistent with ZFC, if ZFC is consistent itself.
The generalised continuum hypothesis asserts that $\aleph_{\alpha}=\beth_{\alpha}$ for all ordinals $\alpha$. Similarly, it and its negation can be consistent with ZFC.
Say we have an "nth continuum hypothesis", which asserts $\aleph_{\alpha}=\beth_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha\leq n$ and $\aleph_{\alpha}<\beth_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha>n$. Could any of these (and presumably their negations) be consistent with ZFC? Furthermore, would it work for $\alpha$ being a limit ordinal, or would we have to restrict $\alpha$ to successor ordinals to make these to meaningfully work?

See Easton's theorem. Also, the mathoverflow questions How far wrong could the Continuum Hypothesis be? and Solutions to the Continuum Hypothesis and these others. Also, this 9 January 2008 sci.math post has some historical information (and may be more background-accessible) about work on this topic in the 1960s, from Cohen to Easton.
